# KeyError ['Item'] in DynamoDB get_item Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, keyerror

I have connected AWS Lambda to a DynamoDB and there isn't any connection issue.
The lambda Python code runs every time the DB is updated. But I am getting a key error in `response['Item']`. I have gone through the documentation but its all the same and I am confused why the error is coming. As almost on every website there is `response['Item']` and my table also isnt empty, It consists of that item.
Problem specifically for float values and not integer values.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('My table name')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    response = table.get_item(
        Key = {

            "Time": Decimal(4193082887.620961)

        }
           )
    
    print(response['Item'])
```

And the error coming in the lambda console is

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'Item'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 26, in lambda_handler
    print(response['Item'])
```

Just to tell actually I wanted a python program which would give me the latest entries of my table, but for test started with get items. If you could tell me how can i get the latest entries from the table in python, that would be fine.I just edited my data from a float value to integer value, Now its perfectly giving me the integer data of time, but when I am doing the same with a float value, it is giving me errors. it has definately to do something with float and decimal.

Comment: What does your table look like?

Comment: Its a normal dynamodb table with 3 colums. Time, Lat, Lon

Comment: Also its connected to IOT core rules.Thats it

Comment: If the key does not exist then there was no item with a partition key of "Time" that had the value of "4193082887.620961". Have you validated in the console that an item has this value?

Comment: Ya the value is there, even if not it should return a empty value and not error.

Comment: One thing to add is the Time attribute is saving data in float, but as lambda dosent support float, I converted it into decimal. If that counts.

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question. If you can solve that issue.

Comment: Can you once print the response and post it here

Comment: I just edited my data from a float value to integer value, Now its perfectly giving me the integer data of time, but when I am doing the same with a float value, it is giving me errors. it has definately to do something with float and decimal.

Comment: `{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'The ID', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Fri, 03 Jul 2020 10:09:09 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '2', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'ID again', 'x-amz-crc32': '2755614147'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}`

Comment: Could you tell me how can I get the latest added column or data from dynamodb. I am struggling.

Comment: do you mean last added entry (row)??

Comment: yes, I want to update the last added row.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo doesn't work like an RDMS..

Assuming the `RequestId` mentioned in one of your comments is the hash key of the table, then GetItem() (and Query()) only works on RequestId.  You could Scan() the entire table looking for Time=4193082887.620961, but that will be costly since the entire table would be read.

What you would need to do is set up a [Global Secondary Index (GSI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) which uses time as it's hash key.  Now you can Query() the GSI for the record you want.

However, one of your later comments mentions you're really interested in getting the last row added, without actually knowing the time.

In that case, instead of using Time as the hash key in your GSI, you'd want a dummy hash key value and use time as a sort key.  Now you Query() the GSI using just the hashkey and with the `"ScanIndexForward" = false` and `Limit=1' properties set.

That will give you the most recent record.